# Virtuemart: Echo order_number on cart/order_done page

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-2.5, virtuemart

Now in the page **views/cart/tmpl/order_done.php** there is `echo $this->html`. How can I echo order_number as single record? `$this->order_number` and `$order['details']['BT']->order_number` don't work. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**order_done.php**

```
require_once(JPATH_VM_ADMINISTRATOR.DS.'models'.DS.'orders.php');
$order = VirtueMartModelOrders::getOrder($this->cart->virtuemart_order_id);
echo $order['details']['BT']->order_number;
```